# plupload - upload button works only if click is triggered programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I am using plupload 1.5.7. I have two buttons on page:

[image: buttons]

First one (Add new attachment) was used as browse_button in plupload configuration. When I click it, it doesn't work. Click event is executed, but file browser is not opened. But there is second button (Trigger add new attachment click), which only does this:

```
$('#TriggerAddNewAttachmentClickButton').click(function() {
    $("#AddNewAttachmentButton").click();
})
```

So it only triggers click of the first button. It works fine. Clicking it opens file browser.

How is this possible? This behavior is consistent between Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Obviously this is security related, because plupload uses tricks to hide input, but second method is not safer. I can't reproduce this issue in jsfiddle, it exists only in specific context, but maybe there is someone, who ecountered similar behaviour.

Comment: I guess I remember I had this kind of problem when the container was not visible upon plupload initialization. Could it be the same problem ?

Comment: @jbl: I see it on screen during initialization. It is shown in popup, but popup is visible. I even added button in popup to init plupload, instead of automatic mechanism. But I can't be sure how browser calculates it.

Comment: can you make the problem available on a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @jbl: As I wrote in question, I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry, should have re-read the question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar issue with `plupload`.  I digged into this issue for hours, and finally I find the reason.  As @jbl said:

> I guess I remember I had this kind of problem when the container was not visible upon plupload initialization. Could it be the same problem ?

The way of `plupload` working is as following:

Remember you need to set a `browse_button`?  Actually the `plupload` will create an **input[type="file"]** for each `browse_button`.  In normal situation, the size and position of the **input[type="file"]** will be the same with the `browse_button` exactly.  So when you click the `browse_button`, it's not the button trigger a file chooser dialog popping up, it's the **input[type="file"]**.

But when you set the `browse_button` container something like: `display:none`(we say, **inactive**), and after that even you set back the `display:block`(we say, **active**), the width and height of the **input[type="file"]**'s parent container would be zero some time.

My quick fix solution for this issue is as following:

I measure the position and size of the `browse_button` when change the state of the container from **inactive** to **active**.  Then I'll manually set the position and size to the hidden **input[type="file"]**;

Following is some sample code:

```
var $btn = $currPanel.find(".browse_button");
var w = $btn.outerWidth();
var h = $btn.outerHeight();
var position = $btn.position();
var $hiddenInputDiv = $currPanel.find(".moxie-shim");
$hiddenInputDiv.height(h);
$hiddenInputDiv.width(w);
$hiddenInputDiv.css(
{
    top: $btn.css("margin-top"),
    left: position.left
});
```